# How can we color the plotly bar by some condition in plotly python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, data-visualization, plotly-dash

I want to color my Bar "Red" when below zero and "light green" when above zero in plotly python.
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plotly: How to colorcode plotly graph objects bar chart using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61892036/plotly-how-to-colorcode-plotly-graph-objects-bar-chart-using-python)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, would be great if you drop a snippet of your code. That way we could for instance figure out whether ur using px or go, and what the df looks like.

Nevertheless, heres the fix:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
values = [10, -100, 22, 45, -57]
threshold = 0

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=[0,1,2,3,4], y=values, marker=dict(color=['green' if value > threshold else 'red' for value in values])))
```

marker_color can take a list in python, and list comprehension is an easy to read, and efficient method.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways is creating bins. In your case, there would be 2 bins: +ve values and -ve values. Each bin may be assigned a color as you need.

The following example solves it:

https://community.plotly.com/t/different-colors-for-bars-in-barchart-by-their-value/6527/7