# How to format plotly legend when using marker color?

Tags: python, plotly-python

I want to follow up on this post: [Plotly: How to colorcode plotly graph objects bar chart using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61892036/plotly-how-to-colorcode-plotly-graph-objects-bar-chart-using-python).

When using plotly express, and specifying 'color', the legend is correctly produced as seen in the post by vestland.

This is my plotly express code:

```
data = {'x_data': np.random.random_sample((5,)),
        'y_data': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
        'c_data': np.random.randint(1, 100, size=5)
       }

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

fig = px.bar(df,
             x='x_data',
             y='y_data',
             orientation='h',
             color='c_data',
             color_continuous_scale='YlOrRd'
            )
fig.show()
```

But when using go.Bar, the legend is incorrectly displayed as illustrated here:

[image]

This is my code using graph objects:

```
bar_trace = go.Bar(name='bar_trace',
               x=df['x_data'],
               y=df['y_data'],
               marker={'color': df['c_data'], 'colorscale': 'YlOrRd'},
               orientation='h'
              )

layout = go.Layout(showlegend=True)

fig = go.FigureWidget(data=[bar_trace], layout=layout)

fig.show()
```

I'm learning how to use FigureWidget and it seems it can't use plotly express so I have to learn how to use graph objects to plot. How do I link the legend to the data such that it works like the plotly express example in vestland's post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really comes down to understanding what a high level API (**plotly express**) does.  When you specify *color* in *px* if it is categorical it creates a trace per value of categorical.  Hence the below two ways of creating a figure are mostly equivalent.  The legend shows an item for each trace,  not for each color.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"x":np.linspace(0,10,10), "y":np.linspace(5,15,10), "color":np.random.choice(list("ABCD"),10)})

px.bar(df, x="x", y="y", color="color", orientation="h").show()

fig = go.Figure()
for g in df.groupby("color"):
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=g[1]["x"], y=g[1]["y"], name=g[0], orientation="h"))

    
fig
```

#### supplementary based on comments

- you do not have to use **graph objects** if you are using `FigureWidget()` as demonstrated by second figure, create with **plotly express** and then generate `FigureWidget()`
- for continuous data normal pattern is to use a single trace and a colorbar (also demonstrated in second figure).  However if you want a discrete legend, create a trace per value in *c_data* and use https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.colors.html `sample_colorscale()`

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.colors
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# simulate data frame...
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "x_data": np.linspace(0, 10, 10),
        "y_data": np.linspace(5, 15, 10),
        "c_data": np.random.randint(0, 4, 10),
    }
)

# build a trace per value in c_data using graph objects ... correct legend !!??
bar_traces = [
    go.Bar(
        name="bar_trace",
        x=d["x_data"],
        y=d["y_data"],
        marker={
            "color": plotly.colors.sample_colorscale(
                "YlOrRd",
                d["c_data"] / df["c_data"].max(),
            )
        },
        orientation="h",
    )
    for c, d in df.groupby("c_data")
]

layout = go.Layout(showlegend=True)

fig = go.FigureWidget(data=bar_traces, layout=layout)
fig.show()

fig = px.bar(
    df,
    x="x_data",
    y="y_data",
    color="c_data",
    orientation="h",
    color_continuous_scale="YlOrRd",
)
fig = go.FigureWidget(data=fig.data, layout=fig.layout)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm new to plotly and also not a developer. But can you also explain how it works with continuous data? I really can't find anything in the documentation to figure this out.

Comment: with continuous data, typically a colorbar is used which for a range of values assigns a color.  so typically with a continuous series you do not use a legend like in your screen shot but a colorbar.  the permutations of options is large, I can only explain in abstract way as you have not provided how you generated your bar figure

Comment: I've edited my original post to include my code sample. I basically tried to replicate the parameters in plotly express for the graph object.

Comment: ok - have added supplementary update to show a) making a continuous color scaler discrete in graph objects with legend showing a value for each discrete value b) how to use continuous with plotly express and figure widget

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realise I don't have to use graph objects when using FigureWidget(). The documentation somehow implied to me I can't use plotly express as it only has the graph object example.