# How to change colour for each specific bar in bar plot using plotly express?

Tags: python, dataframe, charts, plotly, plotly-python

I am using python and plotly in order to design a bar plot for the mean rating of certain categories in the data set I am using. I got the bar chart nearly how I want it however I would like to change the color for each specific bar in the plot but can't seem to find a clear way on how to do this online.

Data Set

```
from pandas import Timestamp
pd.DataFrame({'id': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5},
              
 'overall_rating': {0: 5, 1: 4, 2: 5, 3: 5, 4: 4},
 'user_name': {0: 'member1365952',
  1: 'member465943',
  2: 'member665924',
  3: 'member865886',
  4: 'member1065873'},
 'date': {0: Timestamp('2022-02-03 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2022-02-03 00:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2022-02-02 00:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2022-02-01 00:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2022-02-01 00:00:00')},
 'comments': {0: 'Great campus. Library is always helpful. Sport course has been brill despite Civid challenges.',
  1: 'Average facilities and student Union. Great careers support.',
  2: 'Brilliant university, very social place with great unions.',
  3: 'Overall it was very good and the tables and chairs for discussion sessions worked very well',
  4: 'Uni is nice and most of the staff are amazing. Facilities (particularly the library) could be better'},
 'campus_facilities_rating': {0: 5, 1: 3, 2: 5, 3: 4, 4: 4},
 'clubs_societies_rating': {0: 5, 1: 3, 2: 4, 3: 4, 4: 4},
 'students_union_rating': {0: 4, 1: 3, 2: 5, 3: 5, 4: 5},
 'careers_service_rating': {0: 5, 1: 5, 2: 5, 3: 5, 4: 3},
 'wifi_rating': {0: 5, 1: 5, 2: 5, 3: 5, 4: 3}})
```

Code Used

```
# Plot to find mean rating for different categories
fig = px.bar(df, y=[df.campus_facilities_rating.mean(), df.clubs_societies_rating.mean(),
                    df.students_union_rating.mean(), df.careers_service_rating.mean(), df.wifi_rating.mean()],
                x=['Campus Facilities', 'Clubs & Societies', 'Students Union', 'Careers & Services', 'Wifi'],
                labels={
                    "y": "Mean Rating (1-5)",
                    "x": "Category"},
                title="Mean Rating For Different Student Categories")

fig.show()
```

UPDATED ATTEMPT

```
# Plot to find mean rating for different categories
fig = px.bar(df, y=[df.campus_facilities_rating.mean(), df.clubs_societies_rating.mean(),
                    df.students_union_rating.mean(), df.careers_service_rating.mean(), df.wifi_rating.mean()],
                x=['Campus Facilities', 'Clubs & Societies', 'Students Union', 'Careers & Services', 'Wifi'],
                labels={
                    "y": "Mean Rating (1-5)",
                    "x": "Category"},
                title="Mean Rating For Different Student Categories At The University of Lincoln",
                color_discrete_map = {
                    'Campus Facilities' : 'red',
                    'Clubs & Societies' : 'blue',
                    'Students Union' : 'pink',
                    'Careers & Services' : 'grey',
                    'Wifi' : 'orange'})

fig.update_layout(barmode = 'group')

fig.show()
```

Output just gives all bars as blue.

Comment: Can you specify how you intend to map colors to bars? Do you have a list that contains the color for each bar in this plot? Do you have cutoff bar values for different colors? Should the bar value be represented by a color? Should groups be represented by a color? [Here are several of these possibilities already covered.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61902566/8881141)

Comment: @Mr.T I basically want to choose what colour i assign each x value, so e.g set Campus Facilities to Red, set Students Union to Blue etc. How would do this.

Comment: Please don't post images of code/data/error messages. Post the text directly here on SO. Nobody wants to type text from an image.

Answer (score 6):

In general, you can use `color_discrete_map` in `px.bar()` to specify the color of each bar ***if you've defined a category*** such as `color="medal"` like this:

```
color_discrete_map={'gold':'yellow', 'silver':'grey', 'bronze':'brown'}
```

#### Plot:

[image]

#### Complete code for general approach with data sample:

```
import plotly.express as px

long_df = px.data.medals_long()

fig = px.bar(long_df, x="nation", y="count", color="medal", title="color_discrete_map={'gold':'yellow', 'silver':'grey', 'bronze':'brown'}",
            color_discrete_map={'gold':'yellow', 'silver':'grey', 'bronze':'brown'})

fig.update_layout(barmode = 'group')

fig.show()
```

#### Edit after OP provided data sample

In the case of your particular dataset and structure, you can't directly apply `color='category` since the different categories are spread accross several columns like this:

[image]

There's one way reach your goal using `go.Figure()` and `fig.add_traces()`, but since you seem most interested in `px.bar()`, we'll stick to `plotly.express`. In short `go.Figure()` would require no particular data wrangling to get what you want, but setting up the figure would be a bit more messy. When it comes to `plotly.express` and `px.bar`, the exact opposite is true. And once we've made some changes to your dataset, all you need to build the figure below is the following snippet:

```
fig = px.bar(dfg, x = 'category', y = 'value',
             color = 'category',
             category_orders = {'category':['Campus Facilities','Clubs & Societies','Students Union','Careers & Services','Wifi']},
             color_discrete_map = {'Campus Facilities' : 'red',
                                    'Clubs & Societies' : 'blue',
                                    'Students Union' : 'pink',
                                    'Careers & Services' : 'grey',
                                    'Wifi' : 'orange'})
```

[image]

#### Complete code with all data wrangling steps:

```
from pandas import Timestamp
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5},
              
 'overall_rating': {0: 5, 1: 4, 2: 5, 3: 5, 4: 4},
 'user_name': {0: 'member1365952',
  1: 'member465943',
  2: 'member665924',
  3: 'member865886',
  4: 'member1065873'},
 'date': {0: Timestamp('2022-02-03 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2022-02-03 00:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2022-02-02 00:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2022-02-01 00:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2022-02-01 00:00:00')},
 'comments': {0: 'Great campus. Library is always helpful. Sport course has been brill despite Civid challenges.',
  1: 'Average facilities and student Union. Great careers support.',
  2: 'Brilliant university, very social place with great unions.',
  3: 'Overall it was very good and the tables and chairs for discussion sessions worked very well',
  4: 'Uni is nice and most of the staff are amazing. Facilities (particularly the library) could be better'},
 'campus_facilities_rating': {0: 5, 1: 3, 2: 5, 3: 4, 4: 4},
 'clubs_societies_rating': {0: 5, 1: 3, 2: 4, 3: 4, 4: 4},
 'students_union_rating': {0: 4, 1: 3, 2: 5, 3: 5, 4: 5},
 'careers_service_rating': {0: 5, 1: 5, 2: 5, 3: 5, 4: 3},
 'wifi_rating': {0: 5, 1: 5, 2: 5, 3: 5, 4: 3}})

df.columns = ['id', 'overall_rating', 'user_name', 'date', 'comments', 'Campus Facilities',
              'Clubs & Societies','Students Union','Careers & Services','Wifi']

dfm = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['id', 'overall_rating', 'user_name', 'date', 'comments'],
              value_vars=list(df.columns[5:]),
              var_name ='category')

dfg = dfm.groupby(['category']).mean().reset_index()

fig = px.bar(dfg, x = 'category', y = 'value', color = 'category',
             category_orders = {'category':['Campus Facilities','Clubs & Societies','Students Union','Careers & Services','Wifi']},
             color_discrete_map = {
                    'Campus Facilities' : 'red',
                    'Clubs & Societies' : 'blue',
                    'Students Union' : 'pink',
                    'Careers & Services' : 'grey',
                    'Wifi' : 'orange'})

fig.update_yaxes(title = 'Mean rating (1-5)')
fig.show()
```

#### Appendix: Why `dfm` and `dfg`?

`px.bar(color = 'variable')` assigns colors to unique occurences of a series or a pandas column named `'variable'`. But the categories we're interested in your dataframe are spread accross several columns. So what

```
dfm = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['id', 'overall_rating', 'user_name', 'date', 'comments'],
              value_vars=list(df.columns[5:]),
              var_name ='category')
```

does, is to take the following columns:

[image]

and stack them into one column named `variable` like this:

[image]

But that is still the raw data, and you're not interested in that, but rather the mean of each group in that same column. And that is what

```
dfm.groupby(['category']).mean().reset_index()
```

gives us:

[image]

Take a look at [`pd.melt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) and [`df.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) for further details.

Comment: Can you link to `color_discrete_map` in the docs? When looking for something like a ListedColorMap or a keyword that takes a list, I always ended up [here](https://plotly.com/python/discrete-color/).

Comment: @Mr.T Sure! You'll find a little info on `color_discrete_map` on that exact page just a little bit down under [Directly Mapping Colors to Data Values](https://plotly.com/python/discrete-color/#directly-mapping-colors-to-data-values)

Comment: @Mr.T The Plotly docs have got a bunch of little goodies about color spread around all over the place. I tried to gather the most important of them in the post [Plotly: How to define colors in a figure using plotly.graph_objects and plotly.express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63460213/plotly-how-to-define-colors-in-a-figure-using-plotly-graph-objects-and-plotly-e/63460218#63460218)

Comment: Darn it. I was the entire time [on this page](https://plotly.com/python/colorscales/), and now that I was looking for the link, I accidentally found the right one but didn't read it. Thanks.

Comment: @Mr.T You're welcome! That happens all the time with me too =)

Comment: @vestland Hello, I tried using your example but I am just getting all bars returned as blue for some reason no errors, I put the code i attempted in the question (UPDATED ATTEMPTED) can you take a look please? there is also a example of dataframe data I have.

Comment: @patricebailey1998 Please don't share date samples as images, but [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63163251/pandas-how-to-easily-share-a-sample-dataframe-using-df-to-dict/63163254#63163254) instead

Comment: @vestland I have updated the dataset could you take a look now please

Comment: @patricebailey1998 Yeah, I see what's happening. I'll look into it.

Comment: @patricebailey1998 I've included a custom solution to your dataset. Don't hesitate to let me know if it wasn't quite what you had in mind!

Comment: @vestland Thanks for the quick reply, could you please just quickly explain what the dfm and dfg parts of code are doing please, so I am not just blindly copying. Thank you

Comment: @patricebailey1998 I've added a little info about that in an `Appendix`. I hope that makes the whole thing a little clearer.

Comment: @patricebailey1998 You're welcome! Please consider marking my suggestion as the accepted answer. Upvotes are also always welcome if the answer was useful to you.